# Rollback strategy for iotedge device in iothub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

### Context

The current IotEdge deployment is missing a crucial component which is a rollback strategy, while searching in the documentation, nothing specifies how we can get the devices to a previous version.

There's 2 options I considered through my journey of searching for a solution, which one would you opt for and how are you handling this situation ?

### Option 1

Use kubernetes to manage IotEdge deployments, which is in my opinion over-engineered and not intended for managing only deployment, as K8s is an orchestrator with many useful components not essentially made for such scenarios (or am I wrong ?).

#### Pros

- Quick
- Centralized configuration
- Can target multiple iothubs

#### Cons

- Over-engineered
- K8s knowledge (learning curve)

---

### Option 2

The second option is to write custom scripts that handle the deployment/rollback..

#### Pros

- Lightweight solution
- Free (no additional costs)

#### Cons

- Maintenance is hard.
- Slow Build time
- Bug prone

Comment: you can delete the current deployment and it will rollback to the previous one automatically

Comment: If you don't overwrite your deployment in IoT Hub, but instead create a new one with higher priority, rolling back is as easy as removing the newer deployment, or is that what you meant with Option 2?

Comment: @Helikaon How do you delete the deployment ?

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer nop I meant using a script that will create a new deployment file which is identical to the version we want to rollback to and deploy again. But can I remove deployments ?

Comment: I am using the same deployment id for all the deployments, so that's why they get overwritten ? oohhh if it's like that you are my heros !!!

Comment: @Helikaon, if you want to add your solution as an answer, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rollback a deployment you should just delete the current one and IoT Edge will rollback to the previous deployment targeting it. To be clear, I am talking about [deployments at scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-at-scale?view=iotedge-2020-11)

**EDIT: Instead of deleting the deployment, just modify the target condition, that can prevent from a misclick. See the [rollback deployment official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-deployment-monitoring?view=iotedge-2020-11#rollback)**

Comment: perfect !!! I tested it and it's exactly what I needed, you are my hero :D

Comment: I edited the answer with a better approach (using target condition)